# How to customize error for web::Query<> deserialzation errrors in actix_web?

Tags: rust, actix-web

In [docs](https://actix.rs/docs/extractors/),handler gets called if the query deserializes into `Info` successfully, otherwise a 400 Bad Request error response is returned. How to customize the error response?

```rust
use actix_web::{get, web, App, HttpServer};
use serde::Deserialize;

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Info {
    username: String,
}

// this handler gets called if the query deserializes into `Info` successfully
// otherwise a 400 Bad Request error response is returned
#[get("/")]
async fn index(info: web::Query<Info>) -> String {
    format!("Welcome {}!", info.username)
}
```

Comment: look at the doc on error handlers at the end of [this page](https://actix.rs/docs/middleware). You can customize the reponse for specific error codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the key thing is the [FromRequest](https://docs.rs/actix-web/latest/actix_web/trait.FromRequest.html) implementation.
You have two options.

1. Define your own FromRequest

```rust
struct MyQuery(Info);

impl FromRequest for MyQuery {
   type Error = Error; // <--- Your error type here
   type Future = Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<Self, Error>>>>;
   fn from_request(req: &HttpRequest, pl: &mut Payload) -> Self::Future {
        let fut = web::Query<Info>::from_request(req, pl);
        Box::pin(async move {
            if let Some(info) = fut.await? {
                ....
                return Ok(MyQuery(info));
            }
            Err(Error("my error"))
        })
    }

#[get("/")]
async fn index(info: MyQuery) -> String {
    format!("Welcome {}!", info.0.username) 
}
```

2. Get the data from `Request`

```rust
#[get("/")]
async fn index(req: Request) -> Result<String, Error> {
    let query = Query::<HashMap<String,String>>::from_query(req.query_string()).unwrap();
    let username = query.get("username")?;
    Ok(format!("Welcome {}!", username))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another variant using QueryConfig.

In my example it renders it in json with status code and description.

It also handles all query deserialization errors from all routes.

```rust
// Your custom error struct
#[derive(Debug, Serialize)]
pub struct CustomError {
    pub code: u16,
    pub description: String,
}

// Handy constructor
impl CustomError {
    pub fn new(code: StatusCode, description: &str) -> Self {
        CustomError {
            code: code.as_u16(),
            description: description.into(),
        }
    }
}

// Important: implement ResponseError to render as actix_web::Error 
impl ResponseError for CustomError {
    fn status_code(&self) -> StatusCode {
        StatusCode::from_u16(self.code)
            .unwrap_or(StatusCode::INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    }

    fn error_response(&self) -> HttpResponse {
        HttpResponseBuilder::new(self.status_code())
            .insert_header(header::ContentType(mime::APPLICATION_JSON))
            .json(web::Json(self))
    }
}

// Customize your error in the handler
fn query_error_handler(
    err: QueryPayloadError,
    _req: &HttpRequest,
) -> actix_web::Error {
    CustomError::new(StatusCode::BAD_REQUEST, err.to_string().as_str()).into()
}


// Attach an error handler to QueryConfig when setting up the application
let server = HttpServer::new(move || {
   App::new()
      .app_data(
         QueryConfig::default()
            .error_handler(query_error_handler)
      )
      ...
```